# Are there internal algorithms in neo4j for community detection?

Tags: neo4j

`Gephi` uses `Louvain` algorithm for detection community detection in graphs.
 Are there built-in algorithms in `neo4j` like `Gephi's Louvain` for community detection?
 As I have found in `neo4j's` help docs, there are only shortest path algorithms.

Comment: There is nothing native to Neo4j, but you can use the `Tinkerpop` framework with Blueprints, which Neo4j has already implemented and you can use Furnace, which has several general purpose graph algorithms. Do they perhaps have an algorithm you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't.

However there's also [Dijkstra](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/path/Dijkstra.java) and [A*](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/path/AStar.java) and the [traversal framework](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.java) provides facilities for writing such algorithms (something that at least the Dijkstra algo uses).